# Rendered object color different from viewport color, set in Python

Tags: python

I'm using Blender 2.80. Start in a new scene with no objects. Add a sphere, then go to the Properties panel, Material tab, and set the Base color to pure red in the Principled BSDF. Next, run this script:

```py
    import bpy

    # Get current active object
    ob = bpy.context.active_object

    # Set the material diffuse color
    ob.material_slots[0].material.diffuse_color = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

When I do this, the color of the sphere changes to blue in the viewport. However if I do a render with F12, the color of the sphere is still red. How can I set the material color for rendered images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the viewport setting instead of **node value**.

[NodeSocketColor](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.NodeSocketColor.html)

Use `ob.material_slots[0].material.node_tree.nodes[1].inputs['Base Color'].default_value = (0,0,0,0)`

Comment: not sure if there is a better way to find the socket

Comment: Got it! You have to navigate the nodes making up the material, then get to the specific field. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me on Blender 2.91 but it was a good hint. The solution that worked for me was: `ob.material_slots[0].material.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'].default_value = (0,0,0,0)`